# Dropdown menu positioning with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a dropdown menu and i need to detect the corect position for the submenu. This is how i indent it with jquery:

```
function changeSubcat(catid){
    var position = $('#menuparent_'+catid).position();
    position.left = position.left - 180;
    $('#menu_'+catid).css("left", position.left);
}
```

The real problem is that it works just for a window of the size i worked on, obviosly, so i need to optimize it to work on other dimensions. First i thought i should use another method than          `position()` , but i haven't found a better one. Sorry for not providing the html code but it is a little furry.

Comment: @decebakl, please fix the formatting of your code in the question. It's a pain to read it. Thanks.

Comment: And add an HTML/CSS snippet as well if possible

Comment: And what should be the 'corret position' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why do you use margin left and left at the same time to position the element. Using only

```
function changeSubcat(catid) {
    var position = $('#menuparent_'+catid).position();
    // maybe add a little something to position.top to make the menus not overlap
    $('#menu_'+catid).position(position);
}
```

should work. At times I find that `position()` does not work, and instead you can also try `offset()`. And in some rare cases I have also had problem with both `position()` and `offset()` in which case you can use `$('#menuparent_'+catid)[0].offsetTop` and `$('#menuparent_'+catid)[0].offsetLeft` to get and set the position.

Edit: And by the way, you don't have to parse the position.left or right since they are already integers.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you just want to positon the dropped element. Why do you use JS for this at all? Would not [the pure CSS solution](http://jsfiddle.net/spliter/vWDvy/) Solve your issue?

Comment: it was too much information to be modified on trying this solution for me, so i've chosen the handiest one for me.